# css padding for image alt text

Tags: css, image, alt

I want to give the img alt text padding so it doesn't directly touch the border but I don't want my image to have padding when it was loaded correctly.

Can I give just the alt text padding without it affecting the styling for normal images?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The utility of the alt text is to describe the image for search engines and screen readers. It's not visible unless the image fails loading. Maybe what u are looking for is an image caption?

Quoting another post in stack overflow: "You cant style the alt attribute directly in css. However the alt will inherit the styles of the item the alt is on or what is inherited by its parent."

Comment: That's unfortunate. I guess I have to use javascript. :(